# How can i catch (with get_posts) attachment file (pdf, images) from a post when i have only inserted it from media library and it isn't upload for it?

Tags: attachments, get-posts

I'm sorry for my english.
I discover a strange behavior in WP get_posts when i try to detect from  a post an attachment (in my case a pdf file) inserted from the library. This is my code:

```
$my_query_referenze = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'referenze', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ) );
                while ( $my_query_referenze->have_posts() ) : $my_query_referenze->the_post();
                    $content_referenze = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
                    $idpost = $my_query_referenze->post->ID ;
                    $args_referenze = array(
                        'post_type' => 'attachment',
                        'post_parent' => $idpost,
                        'numberposts' => 1,
                        ); 
                    $attachments_referenze = get_posts($args_referenze);
                    if ( $attachments_referenze ) {
                        foreach ( $attachments_referenze as $attachment_referenze ) {
                            $indirizzoallegato_referenze= wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_referenze->ID , false );
                        }
                    }
```

If i upload a file and i attach it this code works properly. If i try to attach a file from the media library it doesn't work.

I found a  [discussion in WP official forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_children-and-get_posts-not-working) where the people say that there isn't a solution for this case but is it possible?

Isn't there any way to catch the images in both the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload a media from a post, the `post_parent` attribute is setted to the post ID you are uploading from.
Not so when you simple insert a post from the library: in that case if the media was already attached to a post, its `post_parent` is already setted, and once a media can have only one parent, **you can't get the media using `get_posts`**.

However, there are a lot of ways you can do the trick. If your aim is simply output something using the url of the media, probably best choice is a shortcode.

If you need the url to *do* something, you can use a regex to extract the pdf urls from the post content.

If you are using WP 3.7+, there is a function [`wp_extract_urls`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_extract_urls) that help you a lot to perform that task.

Here I'm posting a general function to extract urls form a post content and collect them by their extension:

```
function post_media_urls( $target = '' ) {
  if ( empty($target) )  {
    $target = get_the_content();
  } elseif ( is_numeric($target) ) {
    $post = get_post($target);
    $target = empty($post) ? FALSE : $post->post_content;
  }
  if ( empty($target) ) return false;
  // apply filters to support shortcodes
  $target = apply_filters('the_content', $target);
  // extract urls
  $urls = wp_extract_urls( $content );
  $out = array();
  if ( ! empty($urls) ) {
    // parse only several media extensions, but allow filtering 
    $exts = apply_filters( 'post_media_urls_exts', array('jpg','gif','png','pdf') );
    foreach( $urls as $url ) {
      $ext = strtolower( pathinfo( basename($url) , PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
      if ( $ext === 'jpeg' ) $ext = 'jpg';
      if ( ! empty($ext) && in_array( $ext, $exts) ) {
        if ( ! isset($out[$ext]) ) $out[$ext] = array();
        $out[$ext][] = $url;
      }
    }
  }
  return $out;
}
```

This function can be used in 3 ways. First is passing a post id:

```
$urls = post_media_urls(10);
```

Second is pass a post content (any string, indeed):

```
$urls = post_media_urls($post->post_content);
```

Third is using it inside a loop, without any argument, will be used the current post content:

```
$urls = post_media_urls();
```

In all 3 cases, what you get is an associative multidimensional array of urls where first level keys are file extensions (lowercased), something like:

```
Array(
  [pdf] => Array(
     [0] => 'http://example.com/wp-content/2014/01/sample.pdf',
     [1] => 'http://example.com/wp-content/2014/01/sample2.pdf'
  ),
  [jpg] => Array(
     [0] => 'http://example.com/wp-content/2014/01/sample.jpeg',
     [1] => 'http://example.com/wp-content/2014/01/sample2.jpg',
  ),
  [gif] => Array(
     [0] => 'http://example.com/wp-content/2014/01/sample.gif',
  )
)
```

In your example, the function should be used like this:

```
$args = array( 'category_name' => 'referenze', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') );
$my_query_referenze = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $my_query_referenze->have_posts() ) : $my_query_referenze->the_post();
  $content_referenze = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content() );
  $attachments_referenze = post_media_urls();
  // to get only pdf
  if ( ! empty($attachments_referenze) && isset($attachments_referenze['pdf']) ) {
    foreach ( $attachments_referenze['pdf'] as $pdfurl ) {
      $indirizzoallegato_referenze = $pdfurl
    }
  }
endwhile;
```

Of course this function can be used **only if the media urls you want to retrive are inserted inside the post content**.

**An additional note.** The function do not parse all the urls, but only the urls that end with a set of specific file extensions, in this way any web link (e.g. to other site pages) are skipped.
I've used a very restricted set of extensions, but I've also inserted a filter `'post_media_urls_exts'` to allow changing the allowed extensions.

Comment: Thanks, you are really great!!!! Now i study your solution and i try to implement it in my code and i let you know. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.